# How to get imageURL out of HTML tag

Tags: html, ios, swift, string

I need to strip out the HTML tag from the URL which i m getting in the response from server.

I have tried following code but it's not helping me. Any Ideas??
The String i m geting

"test Discussion for images
"

I have added the extension to retrieve the HTTP string but i m not getting URL accurate.

```
extension String {

       func removeHTMLTag() -> String {

           return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "<[^>]+>", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.regularExpression, range: nil)

        }
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML file so that we can see that.

Comment: @SamiulIslamSami 
I m getting following string. 

"test Discussion for images<div><img src=\"http:\\\\45.35.4.250\\MvestUploadContainer\\7e3ba5ba-000b-4dc4-ae6e-a4bc8d59088c.png\"><br></div>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup) you can get imageURL

```
let doc = try SwiftSoup.parse("<div id=div2><p>How are you?</p><div id=div3><img src=http://example.com/test.png></div></div>");
for element in try doc.select("img").array(){
    try print(element.attr("src"))
}
**Output**
//http://example.com/test.png
```

Comment: Thank you.
This helped me after trying tons of solution 

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
 func removeHTMLTags(for regex: String!, in text: String!) -> [String] {
    do {
        let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: regex, options: [])
        let nsString = text as NSString
        let results = regex.matches(in: text, range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        return results.map { nsString.substring(with: $0.range)}
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("invalid regex: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        return []
    }
}
```

Call this function -

```
let text = "test Discussion for images<div><img src=\"http:\\\\45.35.4.250\\MvestUploadContainer\\7e3ba5ba-000b-4dc4-ae6e-a4bc8d59088c.png\"><br></div>"
let url = removeHTMLTags(for: "(http[^\\s]+(jpg|jpeg|png)\\b)", in: String(text))
print(url[0])
```

Output - `http:\\45.35.4.250\MvestUploadContainer\7e3ba5ba-000b-4dc4-ae6e-a4bc8d59088c.png`